# Оптимизация метода popBack для собственной реализации списка

Tags: c++

Пишу собственную реализацию списка, написал метод popBack, но как мне кажется, он слишком перегружен условными операторами, что должно сказаться на производительности(да и в целом выглядит так себе), можно ли как нибудь его оптимизировать, чтобы выглядел не так ужасно?

```
void popBack() {
  if (head == nullptr) {
    return;
  }
  if (head->next == nullptr) {
    delete head;
    head = nullptr;
  }
  else {
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    Node* curr = head;
    while(curr->next != nullptr) {
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(prev != nullptr) {
      delete curr;
      prev->next = nullptr;
    }
  }
  size--;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да в принципе нормальный метод. Есть немного замечаний по стилю:

- это не метод, а просто функция. Если это метод класса (что было бы хорошо), нужно это указать
- можно догадаться по реализации, что список однонаправленный, но это же могла быть и логическая ошибка в реализации? Может список двунаправленный?
- popback() означает извлечение элемента из списка, а не просто удаление, т.е. метод наверное должен возвращать копию элемента списка. Но это просто замечание, Вы сами выстраиваете логику работы списка.
- поскольку у списка есть параметр `size` то проверять на пустой список и список из 1 элемента можно не по указателям, а саму переменную - будет чуть-чуть быстрее
- последняя проверка `if(prev != nullptr)` лишняя, т.к. Вы уже проверили ситуацию когда в списке 1 элемент, т.е. это условие всегда `true`
- откуда в функции берутся переменные `head` и `size` можно конечно догадаться. Это либо переменные в экземпляре класса, либо глобальные переменные. Но лучше не догадываться, а обозначить прямо. И имена им дать осмысленные, отличающиеся от локальных переменных. Что-то типа `MyListHead` и `MyListSize` - для глобальных переменных
- хоть список и однонаправленный, ничего не мешает хранить указатель не только на начало списка, но и на конец. Точнее лучше хранить указатель на предпоследний элемент (для однонаправленного списка), хотя логика усложняется. В этом случае цикл становится не нужным, сложность работы с линейной O(N) уменьшается до константной.
- использование глобальных переменных - не очень удачная мысль с точки зрения стиля и концепции инкапсуляции в ООП. Либо `popback()` это метод класса, который имеет доступ только к переменным экземпляра этого класса, либо внешняя функция, и тогда список лучше передать по ссылке или указателю, как параметр.

```
struct Node {}

struct MyList
{
  Node *Head = nullptr;
  Node *Tail = nullptr;
  int Size = 0;
};

Node popBack(MyList& List)
{
  if(List.Head == nullptr) 
  {
    return Node();
  }
  ...
}
// ---- либо классом
class MyList
{
  private:  
  Node *Head, *Tail;
  int Size;

  public:
  MyList() : Head(nullptr), Tail(nullptr), Size(0) {}
  Node popback();
};

void main()
{
  MyList list;
  list.popback();
}
```